# Windows-1252 encoding through byte[]

Tags: c#, string, winapi, encoding, utf-8

I'm making use of the Setup... methods (such as [SetupGetLineText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to read some content from inf files (I need this, not interested in a generic ini parser). These methods use Windows-1252 encoding and I need this to be converted to Unicode. I got this working with a string, such as this (input is of type string):

> Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(input));

Even though this works fine, you can also immediately retrieve the bytes from the SetupGetLineText method (and others). However, I'm not entirely sure on how to convert the bytes now as they are different from what Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) returns. To make this a bit more clear I've uploaded a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUZaN.png) of the current situation. As you can see, the majority of the characters match (ignore the 0s), but there are a couple of situations with differences. For example, [4] and [5] are 26 and 32, whereas the string variant has just 130 listed. How can I get from 26 and 32 to 130? Or perhaps better, how can I directly go from the byte array to a UTF-8 string?

Some code:

```
public static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE = new IntPtr(-1);

public const int INF_STYLE_OLDNT = 0x00000001;

public const int INF_STYLE_WIN4 = 0x00000002;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InfContext
{
    IntPtr Inf;
    IntPtr CurrentInf;
    uint Section;
    uint Line;
}

[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetupGetLineText([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref InfContext context, IntPtr infHandle, string section, string key, string returnBuffer, int returnBufferSize, out int requiredSize);

[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetupOpenInfFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string fileName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string infClass, Int32 infStyle, out uint errorLine);

[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetupEnumInfSections(IntPtr infHandle, uint index, string returnBuffer, int returnBufferSize, out int requiredSize);

 [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern bool SetupFindFirstLine(IntPtr infHandle, string section, string key, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]ref InfContext context);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetupFindNextLine([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref InfContext contextIn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref InfContext contextOut);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetupFindNextMatchLine([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref InfContext contextIn, string key, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref InfContext contextOut);


// InfFile class

public InfFile(string path)
{
    _file = path;
}

public bool Open()
{
    uint errorLineNumber;
    _handle = NativeMethodsInf.SetupOpenInfFile(_file, null, INF_STYLE_OLDNT | INF_STYLE_WIN4, out errorLineNumber);

    return _handle != INVALID_HANDLE;
}

    public string EnumSection(uint index)
    {
        int requiredSize;
        string result = String.Empty.PadLeft(75-1);

        bool success = SetupEnumInfSections(_handle, index, result, 75, out requiredSize);
        if (requiredSize > 75)
        {
            result = result.PadLeft(requiredSize - 1);
            success = SetupEnumInfSections(_handle, index, result, requiredSize, out requiredSize);
        }

        return !success ? null : result.Substring(0, requiredSize - 1); // Still needs to be converted to proper encoding.
    }

    public InfLine FindFirstLine(string section)
    {
        return FindFirstKey(section, null);
    }

    public InfLine FindFirstKey(string section, string key)
    {
        InfContext infContext = new InfContext();

        return !SetupFindFirstLine(_handle, section, key, ref infContext) ? null : new InfLine(infContext);
    }

// InfLine class

    public bool FindNextLine()
    {
        return SetupFindNextLine(ref _context, ref _context);
    }

    public bool FindNextMatchLine(string key)
    {
        return SetupFindNextMatchLine(ref _context, key, ref _context);
    }

    public string GetCompleteValue()
    {
        int requiredSize;
        string result = String.Empty.PadLeft(250-1);

        bool success = SetupGetLineText(ref _context, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, result, 250, out requiredSize);
        if (requiredSize > 250)
        {
            result = result.PadLeft(requiredSize - 1);
            success = SetupGetLineText(ref _context, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, result, requiredSize, out requiredSize);
        }

        return !success ? null : result.Substring(0, requiredSize - 1);
    }

// And then use with something like:
using (InfFile file = new InfFile(@"..\..\..\test.inf"))
        {
            if (file.Open())
            {
                uint currentSection = 0;
                string section;
                while ((section = file.EnumSection(currentSection++)) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Section: " + section);
                    var x = file.FindFirstKey(section, null);
                    if (x != null)
                        while (true)
                        {
                            string key = x.GetFieldValue(0);
                            string value = x.GetCompleteValue();
                            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key + " || Value: " + value);
                            if (!x.FindNextLine())
                                break;
                        }
                }
            }
         }
```

Example inf:

```
; German Specific 
[Strings.0007] ; German
Provider="Hewlett-Packard"
Mfg="Hewlett-Packard"
CD="hp cd"

BUTTON_SCAN="Taste "Scannen" gedrückt"
LAUNCH_APPLICATION_SCAN="HP Scansoftware"

; Japanese Specific 
[Strings.0411] ; Japanese
Provider="Hewlett-Packard"
Mfg="Hewlett-Packard"
CD="hp cd"

BUTTON_SCAN="[スキャン] ボタンを押す"
LAUNCH_APPLICATION_SCAN="hp スキャニング ソフトウェア"
```

I need to convert section, key and value using:

```
public static string ConvertToUTF8(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(input)).Trim().Trim('\0');
        }
        catch
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

To get the proper values, otherwise you'll see that they aren't the original characters.

For example:
**Taste "Scannen" gedrückt**
becomes
**Taste Scannen gedrÃ¼ckt**

Without calling ConvertToUTF8 first.

Comment: `How can I get from 26 and 32 to 130` - by using an Encoding conversion, like you are doing (or better, how Jon is suggesting).  Codepage 1252 byte 130(0x82) is a curly comma `‚`.  In UTF8, however, there *are no single byte characters defined above 127(0x7F)*.  The values 26 and 32 represent the two-byte character 0x201A (SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK).  The only comma that translates directly between ASCII and Unicode is 44(0x2C).  Your input string doesn't use that character so you have to convert explicitly.

Comment: This started going down-hill badly with in incorrect pinvoke declaration for the function.  It is a winapi function, it speaks Unicode.  The same kind as C# uses.  Declaring it as a CharSet.Ansi function is a really bad idea, you should use a StringBuilder for the return buffer.  Nobody can see you doing that wrong.

Comment: @ Hans, I already declared it as Unicode, it doesn't matter what you have (Ansi or Unicode). StringBuilder (obvious choice) has the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently converting a string to Windows-1252 and then converting it *back* to a string by interpreting those bytes as UTF-8.

That is *not* working fine - that's broken, basically.

If you've already got a string, it's not in Windows-1252... it's in UTF-16 internally, but you can think of it as a character sequence. If you've *actually* started with a byte array, then you should use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes)` to convert that byte array to a string.

(If you can use `SetupGetLineTextW` instead, you may be able to avoid all this ANSI business entirely.)

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use SetupGetLineTextW or SetupGetLineTextA, both return strings with characters like Ã¥. I had to use the function in the startpost to get this the string back to its original text. I was trying to get the byte array directly to get it directly to UTF-8.

Comment: @Areius: Well if this is meant to be text, there isn't a "byte array" as such. There would be in the original `.inf` file of course, but this function is already interpreting that.

Comment: I know, the problem is that the SetupGetLineTextW isn't returning the text as unicode (like the majority of the other winapi's). I can convert it using above code but it seems strange to me (plus, it's not all that fast) that this is required.

Comment: @Areius: Well, the code you've got seems fundamentally broken to me. It's not clear how you're calling the API - perhaps if you could put some more of that information into the question, it would help.

Comment: That's what I thought as well but I couldn't find any way around it. Maybe you can find it, I added example code to the start post.

Comment: Plus a part of an example inf now.

Comment: @Areius: The code you've posted doesn't include the calls to `Encoding`, which makes it hard to see what's going on...

Comment: The results (section, key and value) were converted using the function I already posted. I've added the full function now to start post (ConvertToUTF8) which should be called on the section, key and value variables  in the while-loop to get the proper encoding, otherwise you'll get the strange values I've mentioned in the start post.

Comment: At this point I think it's really about the details of P/Invoke, which I'm far from an expert on, I'm afraid. I'll remove my answer if you think it's distracting.